# How to generate a number which is divisible by all numbers in a given range?

Tags: algorithms

Suppose I want to find a number that is divisible by all 3 digit numbers (100-999), how do I write a code for that. I know only "1" can divide all 3 digit numbers, but I just want to know the logic.

Comment: 7128865274665093053166384155714272920668358861885893040452001991154324087581111499476444151913871586911717817019575256512980264067621009251465871004305131072686268143200196609974862745937188343705015434452523739745298963145674982128236956232823794011068809262317708861979540791247754558049326475737829923352751796735248042463638051137034331214781746850878453485678021888075373249921995672056932029099390891687487672697950931603520000

Comment: Python-specific questions are off-topic here, so I removed "python" from the title.

Answer (score 3):

The number you see is known as the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

Comment: Another solution is to use a prime sieve, and then to calculate for each prime its highest power appearing in the given range. This should work if the range starts at 1, and might be adaptable to the general case.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think just computing the LCM iteratively is a better idea. It's more flexible (regarding inputs) and scales within polylog(n) terms asymptotically for the [1, n] case compared to the sieve (can't be bothered figuring out which one ends up slightly faster).

Comment: @orlp Not for an interval of numbers. The thing is that one can tell which is going to be the largest exponent of any given prime appearing in any of the numbers in the interval just from the end-points, by doing a binary search, for example. The rest is just to compute all the primes less than or equal to the larger end-point and get their exponents. Them multiply all those primes raised to their exponents.

Comment: @orlp what if I want to find multiple numbers divisible by all numbers in a given range. LCM won't be able to do that. It would only generate 1 number divisible by all the numbers in the given range.

Comment: @orlp Let me define *exponent* in case other people use other names. The **exponent** of a prime $p$ in an integer $a$ is the largest $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^n$ divides $a$.

Comment: @DeepuJohnson The numbers that are simultaneously multiples of all numbers in a list are the multiples of their LCM. So, if you found the LCM you've found all other others. Just take multiples of the LCM.

Comment: @plop What do you mean? The iterative LCM method is $O(n)$ multiplied by the complexity of multiplication, which ends up being some polylog factor. The sieve method *starts* at $O(n \log \log n)$ complexity for the sieve, and then still needs to multiply as well. I do believe both methods are, asymptotically, around the same speed, and the iterative method (that is, $\text{lcm}(a, b, \dots) = \text{lcm}(a, \text{lcm}(b, \dots))$) is more flexible in that $n$ scales with the number of integers, not their size unlike the sieve.

Comment: @DeepuJohnson All numbers that are divisible by some set of integers are multiples of the LCM of that set. If you wish to generate more you can just generate $2l, 3l, 4l, \dots$ where $l$ is the LCM.